# Resurfacing brake rotators without replacing pads

Tags: brakes, chrysler-300c

I had my 300C Chrysler serviced for brake issue some time ago.  They said that there was wear on both front and rear brakes. They changed the front pads, and said that there was pulsation when braking, and excessive run out rear brake rotors, and they resurfaced the rear rotors.

My question is that they resurfaced rear rotors, and supposedly never replaced pads. Is this normal, or likely to occur, because now many miles later they are stating I need pads, which should be covered for life based on their warranty that they give for brake pads.

Comment: What does the paperwork say?

Comment: The paper worked said what I wrote that they resurfaced rotators.  Now they are stating pads are 85% gone, and if they changed them that it's a lifetime guarantee.  I keep my receipts and notice that in the pass they stated that there was west on both front and rear, and changed front pads, but only resurfaced rear rotators, and not charge for pads in back.

Comment: Wear on both front and back meant to type

Answer (score 4):

They might have been trying to save you money, but in the long run it's always best to have rotors and pads replaced at the same time.

To explain more, cheep rotors are very common.  What makes them cheaper? They are thinner and often softer, which means they wear faster and are easily warped.  Resurfacing them is often a waste because the process of machining them can cause them to be even more susceptible to warping.  Some mechanics are real pro's at it and others just throw it on and go have coffee.

As far as pads go, at best they need to be "sanded" to remove any glazing.  Otherwise the pads won't grip as much and can also cause cracking which eventually will make the pad break apart. And again, if the mechanic is thorough they will take time to do this right, others may not.

As you can see this process is fraught with problems, even with a lifetime guarantee you still at least have to take time to go back and then sometimes pay the labor to boot.

So after saying all that, my advice is to always replace pads and rotors together  and use good quality parts.

Take a minute to talk a parts shop with a good reputation, they'll give the skinny and what's cheap and what is good quality for a good price!

Good Luck

M

Answer (score 2):

**It is not normal for a shop to turn the rotors only and not replace the pads.** Maybe they thought they were giving you a price break, but now you end up going back to the shop for more work (ie: more labor to be paid). At this point, if they are worth anything as a shop, they will either have to turn the rotor again or replace them, which again, is more money. Had they done it right in the first place, you'd have paid a little more up front, but would have gained over the long haul . Your brake pads wearing out so quickly is an example of exactly what I'm talking about. Replacement pads are fairly cheap (in the grand scheme of things) and the labor charge for replacement would have already been paid had they done it on your first visit.